# next() promise error handling

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, bluebird

What would be the optimal way for error handling?
I need custom json error messages. It's an API.

```
exports.putCurso = function (req, res, next) {
    util.updateDocument(req.curso, Curso, req.body);
    req.curso.saveAsync()
        .then(function (data) {
            return res.status(201).json({message: 'Curso atualizado.', data: data});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return res.status(500).json({message: 'ERROR!'});
            //OR return next(error); but I need custom json error messages so it doesn't make sense
        })
        .finally(next); //OR return next(error)? redundant?
};
```

Comment: To which instance `Curso` relates to ? Is it a mongoose document?

Comment: Optimally, you'd be able to `return` from the chain and have `next` call on that. I'm not sure what sort of express has for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no mongoose guy but I know one or two things about express and promise

```
exports.putCurso = function (req, res, next) {
  util.updateDocument(req.curso, Curso, req.body);
  req.curso.saveAsync()
      .then(function (data) {
        res.status(201).json({message: 'Curso atualizado.', data: data});
      }, function(error){
        res.status(500).json({message: 'ERROR!'});
      })
};
```

And this is basically all that you need. Based on the implementation, this is probably a normal route because it always returns something (`res.json`) to the client. Therefore, you don't have to call `next` because it is meant for middlewares to call

Also you don't have to return anything because when you call res.json, it basically says that this request ends here, nothing else.

Last but not least, by specification, promise `then` supports 2 functions, the first one is for handing successful case, the 2nd one is for exceptions. So, you don't have to call `catch`

Comment: So in other words **catch()** is only useful when chaining promises? Is catch there just for readability purposes then?

Comment: Yes and Yes. Normally, you will have `done` to indicate the end of the chain and `catch` to handle exceptions. Note that you can have multiple catch phrases to handle different kinds of exception (based on the "class" of each exception)

Answer (score 1):

Considering `Curso` a mongoose document
You can do it like this

```
    req.curso.save(function(err,data){
      if(err) res.status(500).json({message: 'ERROR!'});
      else res.status(201).json({message: 'Curso atualizado.', data: data})
    });
```

EDIT : if you have so many similar issues through out your little huge node application, its worth looking at [rb](https://github.com/nodeofcode/response-builder), then you can do it like

```
var RB = require('rb');
exports.putCurso = function (req, res, next) {
    util.updateDocument(req.curso, Curso, req.body);
    // the below line could have been written in some middleware (eg middleware provided by express.io), so we do get clear code in controller part.
    res.RB = RB.build(res, {  // you may customize your builder yours way, after looking into `rb` docs
      errorStatus : 500, successStatus : 201,
      errorKey : false, successKey : 'data',
      preProcessError : function(){ return { message : 'ERROR!' } },
      addToSuccess : { message : 'Curso atualizado.' }
    });

   //Now only one line in controller
   req.curso.save(res.RB.all);
};
```

Disclosure : i am author of `rb`.

Answer (score 1):

`asCallback` takes a callback which it calls with the promise outcome mapped to the callback convention:

If the promise is rejected, it calls the callback with the error as first argument: `cb(error)`

If the promise is fulfilled, it calls the callback with the value as the second argument: `cb(null, value)`.

```
exports.putCurso = function (req, res, next) {
    util.updateDocument(req.curso, Curso, req.body);
    req.curso.saveAsync()
        .then(function (data) {
            return res.status(201).json({message: 'Curso atualizado.', data: data});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return res.status(500).json({message: 'ERROR!'});
            //OR return next(error); but I need custom json error messages so it doesn't make sense
        })
        .asCallback(next);
};
```

Comment: Assuming that this `putCurso` is a middleware, why do we need to `next` when we have already returned the data (`res.json`) to the client?

Comment: I don't know, I am just saying how to use promises xD